# jQuery UI - How do I distinguish between a drag/resize start event and a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have 3 separate blocks of code that I want to execute.

One is to be executed when the user starts dragging the element (I know how to do that using the draggable start event)

The other one is for when the user starts resizing the element (I know how to do that as well using the resizable start event)

And the third one is for when the user simply clicks on the element (without the intention of either dragging it or resizing it). How do I detect that ?

Does jQuery UI offer a standard way for doing this or is this good enough :

```
$el.resizable({
    start: function ()
    {
        $(this).addClass('animating');
    },
    stop: function (event,ui)
    {
         $(this).removeClass('animating');
    }
}).draggable({
    start: function ()
    {
        $(this).addClass('animating');
    },
    stop: function ()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('animating');
    }
}).click(function ()
   {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            if (!$this.hasClass('animating'))
            {
               console.log('simple click!');
            }
        }, 500);
    });
```

The above isn't very reliable actually, as my click event seems to also fire when a drag action stops (since a click event is registered on mouseup...)

Comment: I've just tested your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/ewwjLooe/) and the click event doesn't fire when a drag action stops.

Answer (score 0):

There are already classes being added when **dragging** or **resizing**. You could use these classes and delegated events to simplify a bit your logic. Like this for example:

```js
$('#element').resizable().draggable();
$(document).on('click', '#element:not(ui-draggable-dragging):not(ui-resizble-resizing)', function() {
  console.log('simple click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<div id="element" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: aquamarine;"></div>"
```